# DNS record validation using sendgrid with Domain.com

Tags: validation, dns, sendgrid, cname

I have been unable to find any help of almost any kind for Domain.com.
I am trying to set up SendGrid domain authentication. All I get is errors.

SendGrid side:

```
Failed
Expected CNAME for "em.....[mywebsite].com" to match "..........sendgrid.net".

Expected CNAME for "s1._domainkey.[mywebsite].com" to match "s1.domainkey.........sendgrid.net".

Expected CNAME for "s2._domainkey.[mywebsite].com" to match "s2.domainkey...........sendgrid.net".
```

On the Domain.com side I set it up like this:

```
**Record**  **Name**             **Content**
CNAME   em....           ..........sendgrid.net
CNAME   s1._domainkey    s1.domainkey...........sendgrid.net
CNAME   s2._domainkey    s2.domainkey...........sendgrid.net
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This question may be better suited for [sf]

Comment: Besides being offtopic, you don't give the name involved so noone can really help. Ask your DNS provider for help. Make sure that a dot is not needed at end of CNAME targets, what you call "content", as some providers require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

If you [lookup the DNS records for your domain](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=wildlifediversity.com&rtype=ALL&dns=google) you will see that there are no listed CNAME records. However, you will also see that your name servers are listed with Digital Ocean. So, making the changes in domain.com will not make a difference to your domain as they no longer control the name servers.

I recommend you log into Digital Ocean and set up the CNAME records for your domain there. Then you'll be well on your way to setting up your Domain Authentication with SendGrid.